Arduino on ttyACM0 disconnects while uploading
Currently I have a project with a Arduino nano RP2040 connect (Docs here). It works perfectly when I program it on a Windows computer, but i have a very strange issue on Arch linux. I use the standard Ide (Site here) with all the necessary and the optional packages installed. In the Ide I have the library for the Arduino Mbed OS Nano Boards too. I had already some trouble with the privileges and the groups but, they are all solved.
Now I try to figure out what is the reason for my Arduino disconnect while I try to upload the default sketch. It's seems like the port have a another task, that is running and the Ide can't inflect that. The serial monitor works perfectly btw. I have absolutely no idea what the actual reason of the problem could bee...
The error message is the standard: Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1

Sometimes the ide doesn't pick up the port correctly make sure you're using the correct port. If the problem persists try checking if the board is genuine. I had a problem where the exact same issue kept popping up. But when i downloaded drivers for the specific knockoff board it was fixed.

The board is original. And I think the port is correct. The system can recognise the Arduino device on ttyACM0. The ide also use this port. And I have the driver.
